# In Java, is there an equivalent of Pascal's typed constants

Tags: java, delphi, pascal

In Delphi / Pascal there is a mechanism by which local variables in a method can remember a value from one method call to the next. This is done using typed constants.  For example:

```
procedure blah();
const
  i: integer = 0;
begin
  i := i + 1;

  writeln(i);
end;
```

On each call to blah() i will increment.  The output will look like:

1
2
3
4
5
...

(each number on separate lines, but the editor here put them on the same line)

Is there an equivalent thing with Java?

Comment: Can't really think of anything else but just a normal class variable which gets incremented by a method. If you make it static, you don't need a method.

Comment: @Stefan - thanks for your answer. I'll check out your last sentence - that seems like something I should know, but don't. Yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest equivalent in Java is a static variable of a class. That has static lifetime, but also has a wider scope than a Delphi assignable typed constant.

In Java there is nothing exactly like Delphi's rather quaintly named *assignable typed constants* that has local scope, but static lifetime. A static class variable is as close as you can get.

In C/C++ you could use a local variable with static storage duration, which has the same semantics as Delphi's assignable typed constants.

Comment: Thanks. Its a pity they aren't available, I used to use them quite often - although it always felt wrong to be varying constants :)

Comment: Personally I never use assignable type constants because 1. I don't like modifying a constant and 2. I then can't use typed constants that are constant. Well, you can always use `{$J+}` but that's pretty awful I think.

Answer (score 5):

you can use static variables. which are initiated once on the first call.
and on each call they save the latest value.

```
public class usingBlah{
    static int i = 0;

    void blah() {
        i++;
        //print here by Log.i or whatever
    }
}
```

here, like your code in delphi, i is defined on the first call and initiated.
on the next calls it will save the latest value.

Comment: you're right, I fixed it. I used it just to explain. see the right code above

Comment: The value in the Delphi code is initialized on startup, not on first call.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for this.  I tried to put the static line inside blah(), but the compiler wouldn't have it.  It seems like local assignable typed constants aren't available in Java.  Which is a pity - I use them quite often in Delphi.

Comment: @Michael. With latest Delphi versions, one would use class variables (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324), which is the equivalent of Java static variables, and in both cases those variables are defined at the class level, not in methods.

Comment: @MichaelVincent it's true, java defines it's own rules for static variables, and it's what you actually found yourself, static variables are defined at class level.

Comment: @J. Gonzalez - I believe assignable typed constants are still available in recent versions of Delphi, but not by default.  Class statics will work fine for me.

Comment: What difference does that make, @Marco? Since the Delphi variable can only be initialized with compile-time constants, never any expression that has side effects, it's impossible to observe from within a program when the variable is really initialized.

Comment: @Rob: I don't know if there is no way, never tried. It was just a fyi.

Answer (score 4):

May be static variables can help you.

Static variables are initialized just one time when the first instance of the class is being created. After that it stores the value.

Comment: This is not correct. Static variables in Java are initialized as soon as the class is referenced the first time. There is no need to create an instance of the class. For example, calling any static class method would cause the initialization of static fields.

Comment: But the answer is clearly wrong though. Nothing to do with instance creation relates to static var init.

Comment: @J.Gonzalez if class A references class B (for example by calling static method B.Foo), both static initializer block code and static field initialization will be executed.

Comment: @mjn. What was I thinking! Of course you're right. I del my comment.